# Why still says no GOPATH though i've set it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go

Both `GoSublime` and `vim-go` tells me that `GOPATH` isn't set, however I've already done this.

my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
```

and I can use `go get` to install gocode to my `~/gopath/bin`
but it prints that: `...:/home/myusrname/gopath/bin: No such file or directory`
for
`~$ $PATH`

Comment: I recommend inspecting the permissions at that location with `ls -la`. Just a random guess, but I would say that `~/gopath/bin` is likely from the root and not your user account so, yes there is in fact no folder `gopath` under your user folder because the root user owns it.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal `drwxrwxr-x  4 myusrname myusrname  4096  Sep 25 12:29 gopath`
gopath locates at `~/gopath`, so i suppose that can't be the problem with permission

Comment: Well so much for that theory.

Comment: I'm curious what the results of `go env` are. That should print out the relevant environmental variables.

Comment: @AndrewN the go env prints
`GOPATH="/home/myusrname/gopath"`
`GOBIN=""`
It's weird that `$GOBIN` is empty

Comment: *checks* My GOBIN isn't set, and from what I remember reading it isn't usually necessary to set it, since it should default to GOPATH/bin anyway. Of course, I don't suppose it would hurt to try setting it manually. I assume ~/gopath/bin does actually exist as a directory? That shouldn't matter either...  To *really* ensure that there's not permissions issue, why not try setting up a go environment for user root?

Comment: @AndrewN I'm really sure there's no permission issue, I create the folder manually through GUI file manager with the normal user

Answer (score 1):

```
~$ $PATH
```

is trying to execute your `$PATH` string, i.e. it's equivalent to writing the contents of the `$PATH` variable into the console and pressing enter. That results in the error you're seeing.

What you want is

```
~$ echo $PATH
```

Comment: however the problem is, my sublime plugins as well as vim plugins cannot detect my `$GOPATH`
also,
`go env` shows
`GOPATH="/home/myusrname/gopath"`
`GOBIN=""`

Comment: Have you restarted after editing your .bashrc? Also, In some distros that file seems to only get loaded in some cases. Maybe try /etc/environment.

Comment: While this is correct, it does not attempt to solve the OP's actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got it: i have to open gvim through shell with $GOPATH set - -!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start gvim with the command:

`bash -lc gvim`

It then starts gvim with the settings in your .bashrc file.

This is from https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/468

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added GOPATH in my .profile

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

And restart my Unbuntu 16.04

Then for my vim-go, I installed the vim-go by the following command in gvim

```
:GoInstallBinaries
```